# Create and write in an xml file in android

Tags: android, xml, motionevent

In my application I am showing some pressure values in a TextView and I want to write these in an xml file also. While any MotionEvent generates, I mean while I am touching the screen everytime the value is changing and I want to write them after each changes is occuring. And that xml file will be saved in to the sdcard(any location). Here's the snipet of my code
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

```
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

     private TextView tvConsole;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1).setOnTouchListener(this);

     tvConsole = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtConsole2);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent mEvent) {
        tvConsole.setText( ""+mEvent.getPressure() );


    // System.out.println("Hardware X " + mEvent.getXPrecision()
      //* mEvent.getX());
    // System.out.println("Hardware Y " + mEvent.getYPrecision()
     // * mEvent.getY());
     System.out.println("Pressure " + mEvent.getPressure());
     System.out.println("Size " + mEvent.getSize());          
     return super.onTouchEvent(mEvent);
        }

}
```

Comment: You've told us what you want, but you have not asked a question.

Comment: Ohh I really forgot to ask the question. Sorry for that. :(
Actually I would ask how to write these in xml file ? As I don't know about writing in any xml file. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the best possible solution for you is to use [`SharePreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Do give the document a good read.

How to go about it, is pretty simple. First, declare your SharedPreference instance.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pressure_values", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This will create an XML file with the name of `pressure_values.xml` in the `/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/` folder. And this file will be private to your own app only.

Now add the details to the XML file created above:

```
Editor editor; = sharedPrefs.edit();

// ADD THE DETAILS TO THE PREFERENCES FILE
editor.putString("Hardware_X", mEvent.getXPrecision());
editor.putString("Hardware_Y", mEvent.getYPrecision());
editor.putString("Pressure", mEvent.getPressure());
editor.putString("Size", mEvent.getSize());

// COMMIT THE ABOVE DATA TO THE PREFERENCE FILE
editor.commit(); // THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT. DO NOT SKIP THIS. THE DATA WILL NOT PERSIST WITHOUT THIS STATEMENT
```

**NOTE:** You will need to run the code above this in the `onTouch()`. This will ensure that new values get written to the XML file.

If the values (for example: `mEvent.getXPrecision()`) are not Strings, convert them to a String before running the code posted above.

To retrieve the values again:

```
String strHardWareX = sharedPrefs.getString("Hardware_X", null);
String strHardWareY = sharedPrefs.getString("Hardware_Y", null);
String strPressure = sharedPrefs.getString("Pressure", null);
String strSize = sharedPrefs.getString("Size", null);
```

Now, you can use the `Strings` to do your function, for example, display the values in a `TextView` for instance.

If you will be accessing the values again, don't forget to instantiate the `SharedPreferences` again.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pressure_values", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Done that. But no file was created. Thing is that there's no folder with my package name in the phone !!! Am I missing something?

Comment: @Rasam: is your phone rooted? As mentioned in the post, it gets created in the system partition and cannot be accessed without root. If you can save and retrieve without errors, you can rest assured the file is there are functioning as it should. :-)

Comment: is there any way to save that file in different location? As no error is shown how can I be assured that the file is created successfully?